# Can I use canonical tags in place of 301 redirect that remove a parameter that had been used by a meta refresh?

Tags: seo, googlebot, meta-tags

For one of my sites, I had used a the meta tag refresh:

​​`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="...;url=...">`

A few months ago, I removed this tag and instead implemented 301 redirects.  The redirects remove the "refresh" parameter. Googlebot crawls these URLs (found in the access logs).

For example:

`https://www.example.com/page?refresh`

now has a 301 redirect to removing the refresh parameter. It redirects to:

`https://www.example.com/page`

I can't figure out if this was the cause of my search engine ranking drop, but about that time, I started losing traffic. Maybe it was a coincidence.

In any case, to date, for all my pages, I have set the canonicals. Now I wanted to understand if it is OK to remove the 301 rules that strip off the refresh parameter. That would just leave everything to Google to manage.

Comment: It is unclear to me why the refresh is there.  One way to stop the indexing is to make sure that the canonical is *https://www.example.com/page*

Comment: Hello,
the site is an online news site, so to update the content at a specific rate, I used the meta refresh tag. I meant, now that I have removed the meta refresh tag from all my pages I have noticed that google has indexed these pages.
So I removed the meta refresh tag from my site and made a 301 redirect from the indexed meta refresh pages to the canonical pages.
I hope I was clearer.
Thank you